# Power Bi - Computing the category for another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

At power BI, i have two table Table_1 and Table_2 both are disconnected. I wanted to take a count of categories when a owner say A is selected count the Product categories for Owner "A" and rest can be blank.

Table 1

| ID | Owner_Name | Prod_Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Red |
| 1 | A | Blue |
| 1 | A | Black |
| 2 | B | Orange |
| 2 | B | Yellow |
| 2 | B | Blue |
| 3 | C | Green |
| 3 | C | White |
| 3 | C | Pink |
| 3 | C | Grey |

Table_2

| Prod_Cat |
| --- |
| Red |
| Blue |
| Black |
| Orange |
| Yellow |
| Blue |
| Green |
| White |
| Pink |
| Grey |

Table_2 - When "A" is selected via Slicer at the report

| Prod_Cat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Blue | 1 |
| Black | 1 |
| Orange | 0 |
| Yellow | 0 |
| Blue | 0 |
| Green | 0 |
| White | 0 |
| Pink | 0 |
| Grey | 0 |

Table_2 - When "B" is selected via Slicer at the report

| Prod_Cat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 0 |
| Blue | 0 |
| Black | 0 |
| Orange | 1 |
| Yellow | 1 |
| Blue | 1 |
| Green | 0 |
| White | 0 |
| Pink | 0 |
| Grey | 0 |

Had tired by creating a calculated column at the Table_2 with count function but not getting the expected outcome.